# Rails XML undefined method `name' for "preview":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view-helpers

**My XML error:**

```
NoMethodError in Admin/xml#index

Showing C:/Rails/asdw/app/views/admin/xml/index.rhtml where line #1 raised:

undefined method `name' for "preview":String

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% update_xml("preview") %>
2: 
3: 
4: <h2>Preview/publish</h2>
```

**My controller:**

```
def index
    @photographer = Photographer.find(:first)
    #render :layout => false
end
```

**My XML helper:**

```
   module XmlHelper
        require 'builder'

            def update_xml(photographer, output="preview") 

                xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new



                 xml.photographer(:name => photographer.name) do    



                  for group in photographer.groups 
                    xml.group(:name => group.name) do 
                    for project in group.projects 
                        xml.project(:name => project.name) do 
                                    for collection in project.collections
                                        xml.collection(:name => collection.name) do 
                                            for image in collection.images
                                                xml.image(image.description, :url => image.image, :id => image.id)


                                            end 
                                        end     
                                    end 
                        end 
                    end
                    end     
                  end       
                end           


                File.open("#{rails_root}/public/xml/#{output}.xml", "w") do |f|
                  f.puts ("#{xml}")
                end 


        end 






end
```

**UPDATE:**

Using `<% update_xml(photographer, "preview") %>`:

```
NameError in Admin/xml#index

Showing C:/Rails/asdasd/app/views/admin/xml/index.rhtml where line #1 raised:

undefined local variable or method `photographer' for #<#<Class:0x47eb990>:0x47ea238>
```

**NEW UPDATE Using** `<% update_xml(@photographer, "preview") %>`:

```
oMethodError in Admin/xml#index

Showing C:/Rails/asdfsadf/app/views/admin/xml/index.rhtml where line #1 raised:

undefined method `groups' for #<Photographer:0x45ca2d8>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <% update_xml(@photographer, "preview") %>
2: 
3: <h2>Preview/publish</h2>
```

Comment: That's some crazy indentation. I'd consider using two or four spaces, consistently--makes it easier for people to help out.

Comment: Could you please include your controller code?

Comment: I have includeded my controller code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try using "<% update_xml(photographer, "preview") %>" instead of <% update_xml("preview") %> in Admin/xml#index, let me know if you get error again!

Comment: I have tried I have opdated my question with the erros in view.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your Photographer model you have a `groups` association such as:

```
has_many :groups
```